# How to make Output cache for tweetsharp twitter feeds in asp net mvc5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, twitter, tweetsharp

I am using tweetsharp nuget package for adding tweets to my website.

I put my partialview on footer and it is visible on everpage of website.

here is my codes on Basecontroller.

```
public PartialViewResult _PartialView_twitter_feed()
    {
        var service = new TwitterService("key", "key");

        service.AuthenticateWith("key", "key");

        IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> tweets = service.ListTweetsOnUserTimeline(new ListTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions { ScreenName="my_screen_name", Count=5 });

        ViewBag.Tweets = tweets;

        return PartialView();
    }
```

and I call it like this on footer view.

```
 @Html.Action("_PartialView_twitter_feed", "base")
```

Now is the question, How can I make output caching or some kind of caching for this implementation on asp net mvc 5?

I dont want to call twitter api in every page view again and again. Because partial view is on footer.

How can I make it only once and show it until user leaves my website?

What can be the best practise to achive this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OutputCache attribute. I hope the following example will help you.

**Controller**

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 6000)]
public PartialViewResult Footer()
{
    return PartialView("Footer");
}

public ActionResult MainPage1()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult MainPage2()
{
    return View();
}
```

**View**

*MainPage1*

```
<h2>MainPage1</h2>

@Html.Action("Footer")
```

*MainPage2*

```
<h2>MainPage2</h2>

@Html.Action("Footer")
```

When user access the `MainPage1` first time, the Footer partial view will return from server. From second time onwards it will return from cache. Even when user access `MainPage2` the footer partial view will return from cache. You can increase the duration seconds based on your requirement